# sql query that select data and find duplicate values in selected records

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server

I'm trying to create a single query that will combine the following two queries.

1st Query:

```
select * from mutual_friends where fb_id =8807531 OR fb_id=102061
```

2nd Query:

```
SELECT name,picture, COUNT(picture) 
FROM mutual_friends
GROUP BY picture
HAVING ( COUNT(picture) > 1 )
```

1st query select data of two id's And then Second Query Find Duplicates In Picture Column

I want the result using a single query

I will be really thankful if anyone can help me over this matter

Comment: why can't you go for simple union if you want both the queries result set

Comment: To work on all RDBMSs simultaneously?

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT name,picture, COUNT(picture) 
FROM mutual_friends
where fb_id = 8807531 OR fb_id = 102061
GROUP BY picture
HAVING ( COUNT(picture) > 1 )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
 SELECT name,picture, COUNT(picture) 
 FROM mutual_friends
 WHERE fb_id = 8807531 OR fb_id = 102061
 GROUP BY picture
 HAVING ( COUNT(picture) > 1 )
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for all ids with duplicate pictures.. Then I suggest your answer as

```
SELECT fb_id, name, picture 
FROM mutual_friends
WHERE picture IN (
    SELECT picture
    FROM mutual_friends 
    GROUP BY picture
    HAVING COUNT(picture) > 1)
```

Or be more specific as your question does not clearly explain what you are looking for.